# Reshaping a data frame by reverse melt

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape, melt

I have a dataset with two sets of observations for 830 and 930. My objective is to reshape my data frame so that there is one `originID` column, one `830` column, and one `930` column, keeping the values under `walking` in their respective hour column. It's basically a reverse reshape.  Is there a quick method to do this in R and what package would be most appropriate?

```
> df
      originId   walking hour
1    359727104  3.440248  830
2    359931904  8.065233  830
3    229873828  3.519326  830
4    359931908 20.758961  830
5    359931909 15.050358  830
6    359727113  3.178191  830
1063 359727104  3.029167  930
1064 359931904  8.093116  930
1065 229873828  3.523732  930
1066 359931908 21.234964  930
1067 359931909 15.701993  930
1068 359727113  2.768297  930
```

I have tried this formula from `reshape2` but it does not produce the correct result.

```
> dcast(df, formula = originId + walking ~ hour)
Using hour as value column: use value.var to override.
    originId   walking 830 930
1  229873828  3.519326 830  NA
2  229873828  3.523732  NA 930
3  359727104  3.029167  NA 930
4  359727104  3.440248 830  NA
5  359727113  2.768297  NA 930
6  359727113  3.178191 830  NA
7  359931904  8.065233 830  NA
8  359931904  8.093116  NA 930
9  359931908 20.758961 830  NA
10 359931908 21.234964  NA 930
11 359931909 15.050358 830  NA
12 359931909 15.701993  NA 930
```

Here is a sample of the data:

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(originId = c(359727104, 359931904, 229873828, 
359931908, 359931909, 359727113, 359727104, 359931904, 229873828, 
359931908, 359931909, 359727113), walking = c(3.44024822695035, 
8.06523297491039, 3.51932624113475, 20.7589605734767, 15.0503584229391, 
3.1781914893617, 3.02916666666667, 8.09311594202899, 3.52373188405797, 
21.2349637681159, 15.7019927536232, 2.76829710144928), hour = c(830L, 
830L, 830L, 830L, 830L, 830L, 930L, 930L, 930L, 930L, 930L, 930L
)), .Names = c("originId", "walking", "hour"), row.names = c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1063L, 1064L, 1065L, 1066L, 1067L, 1068L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: You need to use the `walking`variable as your `value.var`: `dcast(df, formula = originId ~ hour, value.var = 'walking')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `walking`-variable as your `value.var`:

```
dcast(df, originId ~ hour, value.var = 'walking')
```

which gives:

```
   originId       830       930
1 229873828  3.519326  3.523732
2 359727104  3.440248  3.029167
3 359727113  3.178191  2.768297
4 359931904  8.065233  8.093116
5 359931908 20.758961 21.234964
6 359931909 15.050358 15.701993
```

And probably even better:

```
dcast(df, originId ~ paste0('hr_',hour), value.var = 'walking')
```

which gives:

```
   originId    hr_830    hr_930
1 229873828  3.519326  3.523732
2 359727104  3.440248  3.029167
3 359727113  3.178191  2.768297
4 359931904  8.065233  8.093116
5 359931908 20.758961 21.234964
6 359931909 15.050358 15.701993
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `tidyr`:

```
df %>% spread(hour, walking)
```

I would recommend changing the numbers like this using `dplyr` so you don't have to deal with column names starting with numbers:

```
df %>%
  mutate(hour = paste0('hour_', hour)) %>%
  spread(hour, walking)
```

Comment: I get the following error when trying this :  Error in utils::getS3method("as_data_frame", "matrix", envir = asNamespace("tibble")) : unused argument (envir = asNamespace("tibble")) –

Comment: Try restarting your R session and only loading the required packages. If it works, then there is a conflict.